# How to go to a baseball game in Cuba?

Tags: cuba, havana, sport

[How to go to a baseball game in Cuba](http://www.visitcuba.com/2015/12/how-to-go-to-a-baseball-game-in-cuba-the-inside-secrets/):

> The baseball season begins in late August with occasional breaks for
>   the Cuban National team’s international tournaments and culminates
>   with the league’s playoffs beginning in early March

How can I find more information about the games in early March? When and where do they play? For example, near Havana, Trinidad, Santa Clara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this year the season ended earlier than usual, the finals already took place end of January.

Se here:http://www.beisbolencuba.com/series/serie-nacional-beisbol-2016-2017/final

And here:http://www.sportstats.com/baseball/cuba/serie-nacional/

On top of that, many Cuban players are currently busy with the [World Baseball Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_World_Baseball_Classic). I would not expect any serious game to take place in Cuba during this period.

Update: The Classic just finished for the Cuban team, [they lost miserably](http://www.newsday.com/sports/baseball/world-baseball-classic-cuba-vs-netherlands-pictures-1.13259466)...

In case you go to Havana while there is an active baseball season, the place to go to watch a game would be ["Estadio Latinoamericano"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Latinoamericano), and in Santa Clara it would be the ["Estadio Augusto César Sandino"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estadio_Augusto_C%C3%A9sar_Sandino).

There is at least one stadium like those at each province capital.

Answer (score 1):

The season is over in March 2017. I have watched a game in Trinidad on Saturday  morning among some local teams. Entry was free.